# Flask-Sqlalchemy doesn't work as expected when use filter by

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I am triying the following querie

```
record = Record().query.filter(
    Record.id == record_id,
    Record.status.isnot(Status.COMPLETE)
    ).one()
print(record)
```

status is a str and id is a int

```
class Status(str, Enum):
    SCHEDULED = 'SCHEDULED'
    RECORDING = 'RECORDING'
    UPLOADING = 'UPLOADING'
    COMPLETE = 'COMPLETE'
    CANCELED = 'CANCELED'
    FAILED = 'FAILED'

@dataclass
class Record(db.Model, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'records'
    id: int
    status: Status
    start: int
    time_duration:int
    camera_id: int
    bucket_destination:str
    local_video:str
    fail_type:FailType
    acceptance: int

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum(Status), nullable=False, default=Status.SCHEDULED)
    start = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    time_duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    camera_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cameras.id'), nullable=False)
    fail_type = db.Column(db.Enum(FailType))
    local_video = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    bucket_destination = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)    
    acceptance = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=75)
```

But when executing the queries I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''COMPLETE'' at line 3")
[SQL: SELECT records.created_at AS records_created_at, records.updated_at AS records_updated_at, records.id AS records_id, records.status AS records_status, records.start AS records_start, records.time_duration AS records_time_duration, records.camera_id AS records_camera_id, records.fail_type AS records_fail_type, records.local_video AS records_local_video, records.bucket_destination AS records_bucket_destination, records.acceptance AS records_acceptance 
FROM records 
WHERE records.id = %s AND records.status IS NOT %s]
[parameters: (1, 'COMPLETE')]
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Would it work with `Record.status != Status.COMPLETE`? I'm not sure if that's the same thing as `IS NOT` but would be worth a try at least.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to be five months late and also point out something that's pretty minor

in flask-sqlalchemy, you use a singular `=` when filtering. i know in regular sqlalchemy they use `==` but i think that's your issue